# Lambda Statement

Tags: c#, lambda

I am wondering if there is a better way of accomplishing this;

I have an object - one of the property is a Dictionary. I have a set of comma separated values. I need to filter the Dictionary and get only those elements where the Dictionary value matches at least one of the values

This is what I have tried but is there is a shorter way of doing this?

Just to explain:
filterValue is the list of values(E.g. "4,5')

```
List<string> vals = new List<string>();
vals.AddRange(filterValue.Split(new char[]{','}));
List<T> bindingEntities = entities.Where(
             e => {
                foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in e.ExtraProperties)
                {
                    if(vals.Contains(kvp.Value.ToString()))
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Well, you don't need to put the results of the `Split` into a list and you can just do `.Split(',')`.

Comment: Depending on how many values are in the `filterValue`, it might be more worthwhile to use a `HashSet<T>` instead of a `List<T>`. In fact, arrays support the `Contains()` method all the same, so there is no point in creating a `List<T>` at all either: `var vals = filtervalue.Split(new char[] {','});`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ***Any*** function:

```
List<string> vals = new List<string>();
vals.AddRange(filterValue.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
var bindingEntities = entities.Where(
             e => e.ExtraProperties.Any(
             kvp => vals.Contains(kvp.Value.ToString()))).ToList();
```

Comment: Too Good! Short and clean!

Comment: You can even make it shorter if you drop the `List<string>` declaration and use the `string[]` returned from `string.Split`.

Comment: I think the parentheses around ToString() need to be fixed so that it will compile

Comment: @Slugart Nope, they're fine.

Comment: Really, Any() returns a bool and there's ToList() method on bool - just try to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> vals = new List<string>();
vals.AddRange(filterValue.Split(new char[]{','}));
List<T> bindingEntities = entities.Where(
                                         e => e.ExtraProperties.Values.Any(
                                             val => vals.Contains(val.ToString())))
                                  .ToList();
```

or

```
List<string> vals = new List<string>();
vals.AddRange(filterValue.Split(new char[]{','}));
List<T> bindingEntities = from e in entities
                          from val in e.ExtraProperties.Values
                          where vals.Contains(val.ToString())
                          select e;
```

Comment: ExtraProperties does not have Values property

Comment: ExtraProperties is Dictionary right?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze am I mistaken?

Comment: I forgot that it was dictionary. So the answer is no :)

Comment: Well if you think that this downvote is mine, then take my upvote )) good luck

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason aren't you just querying the dictionary object?

```
var result = filterValue.Where(d => d.Value.Contains(val.ToString()).ToList();
```

Now you have the dictionary objects that contain the filter so you can work with them instead of going through the extra step of constructing a bunch of string arrays that you don't really need.